# Getting an Access 2007 table (.accdb extension) in ArcMap programmatically

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, arcgis, esri, arcobjects

I have recently found a script from ArcScripts on how to get an Access table in ArcGIS programmatically and it works well. But this is for Access 2003 (.mdb extension) and earlier. The code is posted below, and I want to know how to modify it for using Access 2007 (.accdb extension) and later databases.

```
Attribute VB_Name = "Access_connect"
Sub Open_Access_Connect()
  'V. Guissard Jan. 2007

  On Error GoTo EH

  Dim data_source As String
  Dim pTable As ITable
  Dim TableName As String

  Dim pFeatWorkspace As IFeatureWorkspace
  Dim pMap As IMap
  Dim mxDoc As IMxDocument
  Dim pPropset As IPropertySet
  Dim pStTab As IStandaloneTable
  Dim pStTabColl As IStandaloneTableCollection
  Dim pWorkspace As IWorkspace
  Dim pWorkspaceFact As IWorkspaceFactory


  Set pPropset = New PropertySet
  ' Get MDB file name
  data_source = GetFolder("mdb")
  ' Connect to the MDB database
  pPropset.SetProperty "CONNECTSTRING", "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _
  & "Data source=" & data_source & ";User ID=Admin;Password="

  Set pWorkspaceFact = New OLEDBWorkspaceFactory
  Set pWorkspace = pWorkspaceFact.Open(pPropset, 0)
  Set pFeatWorkspace = pWorkspace

  ' Get table name
  TableName = SelectDataSet(pFeatWorkspace, "Table")
  ' Open the table
  Set pTable = pFeatWorkspace.OpenTable(TableName)
  'Create Table collection and add the table to ArcMap
  Set mxDoc = ThisDocument
  Set pMap = mxDoc.FocusMap
  Set pStTab = New StandaloneTable
  Set pStTab.Table = pTable
  Set pStTabColl = pMap
  pStTabColl.AddStandaloneTable pStTab

  ' Update ArcMap Source TOC
  mxDoc.UpdateContents

  Exit Sub

EH:

  MsgBox "Access connect: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description

End Sub

Public Function GetFolder(Optional aFilter As String) As String
  ' Open a GUI to let the user select a Folder path name (by default) or :
  ' Set aFilter = "shp" to get a shapefile name
  ' Set aFilter = "mdb" to get an MS Access file name
  ' Return the Folder Path or phath & file name As String
  ' V. Guissard Jan. 2007

  Dim pGxDialog As IGxDialog
  Dim pFilterCol As IGxObjectFilterCollection
  Dim pCurrentFilter As IGxObjectFilter
  Dim pEnumGx As IEnumGxObject

  Select Case aFilter
    Case "shp"
      Set pCurrentFilter = New GxFilterShapefiles
      aTitle = "Select Shapefile"
    Case "mdb"
      Set pCurrentFilter = New GxFilterContainers
      aTitle = "Select MS Access database"
    Case Else
      Set pCurrentFilter = New GxFilterBasicTypes
      aTitle = "Select Folder"
  End Select

  Set pGxDialog = New GxDialog
  Set pFilterCol = pGxDialog
  With pFilterCol
    .AddFilter pCurrentFilter, True
  End With
  With pGxDialog
    .Title = aTitle
    .ButtonCaption = "Select"
  End With

  If Not pGxDialog.DoModalOpen(0, pEnumGx) Then
    Smp = MsgBox("No selection : Exit", vbCritical)
    End
    'Exit Function 'Exit if user press Cancel
  End If
  GetFolder = pEnumGx.Next.FullName

End Function

Public Function SelectDataSet(pWorkspace As IWorkspace, Optional theDataType As String) As String
  ' Open a GUI to let the user select a DataSet into a Workspace
  ' (Table or Request into an MS Access Database or a Geodatabase File)
  ' Set pWorkspace to the DataSet IWorkspace
  ' Set theDataType = "Table" to select a Table name of the DataSet
  ' Return the selected Table or Request Table name As String
  ' V. Guissard Jan. 2007

  Dim aDataset As Boolean
  Dim boolOK As Boolean
  Dim DataSetList As New Collection
  Dim datasetType As Integer
  Dim n As Integer

  Dim pDataSetName As IDatasetName
  Dim pListDlg As IListDialog
  Dim pEnumDatasetName As IEnumDatasetName

  ' Set the Dataset Type
  Select Case theDataType
    Case "Table"
      datasetType = 10
    Case Else
      Answ = MsgBox("Need a Dataset Type : Exit", vbCritical, "SelectDataset")
      End
  End Select

  ' Get the Dataset Names included in the workspace
  Set pEnumDatasetName = pWorkspace.DatasetNames(datasetType)

  ' Create the Dataset Names List Dialog
  aDataset = False
  Set pListDlg = New ListDialog
  pEnumDatasetName.Reset
  Set pDataSetName = pEnumDatasetName.Next
  Do While Not pDataSetName Is Nothing

       pListDlg.AddString pDataSetName.name
       DataSetList.Add (pDataSetName.name)
        Set pDataSetName = pEnumDatasetName.Next
        aDataset = True
  Loop

  ' Open a GUI for the user to select a dataset
  If aDataset Then
    boolOK = pListDlg.DoModal("Select a " & theDataType, 0, Application.hwnd)
    n = pListDlg.choice
    If (n <> -1) Then
        SelectDataSet = DataSetList(n + 1)
    Else
        Sup = MsgBox("No DataSet selected : EXIT", vbCritical, "SelectDataset")
        End
    End If
  End If
End Function
```

Here is the link to the ArcScript: http://arcscripts.esri.com/Data/AS14882.bas

PS I know this code is written in VBA and I don't know if a modified version is in VB.NET or whatever else language.

Thanks,
Adrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to figure out connection properties for ArcObjects, I find it helpful to set up an OleDB connection in arccatalog using the GUI.  Once it tests successfully, I then run this VBA script to list the connection properties, which I can then copy and paste into my code.

```
Sub ListConnProps()
    Dim pGxApp As IGxApplication
    Set pGxApp = Application
    If Not TypeOf pGxApp.SelectedObject Is IGxDatabase Then
        Debug.Print "select a geodb first"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim pGXdb As IGxDatabase2
    Set pGXdb = pGxApp.SelectedObject
    Dim names As Variant, values As Variant
    Debug.Print pGXdb.WorkspaceName.WorkspaceFactoryProgID
    pGXdb.WorkspaceName.ConnectionProperties.GetAllProperties names, values
    Dim l As Long
    For l = 0 To UBound(names)
        Debug.Print names(l), values(l)
    Next l

End Sub
```

**Update:** Here's some code that I tested successfully after downloading the provider from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7554f536-8c28-4598-9b72-ef94e038c891&DisplayLang=en), and a test accdb file from [here](http://www.ms-access2007.com/tutorials/downloads.html).  I wasn't using a password, so couldn't test that.

```
public static void TestOleDB()
{
    IWorkspaceFactory wsf = new OLEDBWorkspaceFactoryClass();
    IPropertySet ps = new PropertySetClass();
    string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        + @"Data Source=D:\Projects\AmberGIS\Forums\MikeGarage\MikeGarage.accdb;"
        + "Persist Security Info=False";

    // if you're using a password, use next line (??)
    //((IOleDBConnectionInfo)wsf).SetParameters(connStr, "");
    ps.SetProperty("CONNECTSTRING", connStr);
    IWorkspace ws = wsf.Open(ps, 0);
    IEnumDatasetName enumDsn = ws.get_DatasetNames(esriDatasetType.esriDTAny);
    IDatasetName dsn;
    while((dsn=enumDsn.Next())!= null)
        Debug.Print(dsn.Name);

}
```

Comment: Remou, I meant to write earlier that I had tried that and it came up with an error.  Kirk, I ran that code and it's nice how it gives the connection string but I got the same error when I put it into my existing code.  The error I got was "5 invalid procedure call or argument".  Is there something else that I'm missing? Or is it an issue that can't be handled properly because it's accdb which doesn't work directly with ArcGIS?

Thanks

Comment: While ESRI doesn't support .accdb files for geodatabases in the same way they support .mdb files, they do support OleDB.  Can you view the tables via your oleDB connection in arccatalog?

You might also try calling IOleDBConnectionInfo.SetParameters on the workspacefactory before calling open with your propertyset.

Comment: Yes, I can view them in ArcCatalog and bring them into ArcGIS.  I tried playing around with the IOleDBConnectionInfo interface but had the same errors.  Is there something else that I'm missing due to that fact that it's accdb? Or can you provide an example of what all needs to fit together in arcobjects in order to get these tables programmatically?  Like what I mean is, what variables and interfaces do I need to link together (from IOleDBConnectionInfo to what?)

Thanks!

Comment: Kirk, somehow I just saw your edited code above.  It works real well and gets into the accdb database to give me the names of each table.  This is great but how do I actually access those tables? I guess in the end I would like to assign the ITable interface to specific tables in that database. I'm sorry if this is obvious and I'm just missing the correct link.  Please let me know!  Thanks!

Comment: Kirk, I figured it out by using IFeatureWorkspace with the IWorkspace interface and then using the "OpenTable" method within.

Answer (score 0):

The connection string for Access 2007 is

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccess2007file.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;
```

So

```
pPropset.SetProperty "CONNECTSTRING", "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
& "Data source=" & data_source & ";User ID=Admin;Password="
```

-- http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007

Comment: Note that OLEDB can't handle a database password, but ODBC can.